# Qual a diferença entre Toolbar.axml e Tabbar.axml?

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Estou começando a trabalhar com Xamarin no Visual Studio 2017, e alguns coisas mudaram. Na parte de android quando eu vou em layout eu deparo com os dois arquivos Toolbar.axml e Tabbar.axml, gostaria de saber quais deles representam o MainPage (a pagina principal) e qual a diferença entre os dois?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem, como ninguém respondeu, então provavelmente a maioria das pessoas que acessaram também não sabe. Estudando aqui a documentação descobrir que esses dois arquivos Toolbar.axml e Tabbar.axml eles são responsáveis apenas pelos itens que irá compor o menu ou a parte superior do meu App especificamente no android, pois o menu podemos editar diretamente em nossa mainpage para ser aplicado de forma geral, que nesse caso será o nosso arquivo principal, a mãe do projeto, nele teremos a parte de layout e lógica de nossa aplicação. E a parte visual do mainpage ela não possui um designer, toda a inserção de labels e demais componentes é tudo feito na unha(via script). Espero que tenho sanado a dúvidas daqueles que ainda não tinham esse conhecimento.